# Laravel 5.2 - Update previous query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this query:

```
Sendqueue::select()
            ->where('userID', Session::get('uid'))
            ->where('campaign', $id)
            ->where('status', 'pending')
            ->update(array(
                'status'      => 'stopped',      
                ));
```

The problem is that the amount of records it has to go through to do the update causes it to take around 15 minutes or so to finish.

I would like to split it up so the select and update queries are separate entities.  Something sort of like this:

```
$pending = Sendqueue::select()
            ->where('userID', Session::get('uid'))
            ->where('campaign', $id)
            ->where('status', 'pending')
            ->get();

$pending->update(array(
            'status'      => 'stopped',      
            ));
```

How would I go about doing this?  Or is there an easier way?

Thanks!

Comment: Could anyone explain why the first query was running suboptimally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't thinking, I figured out the answer.  I had to run the second part in a foreach like so:

```
$records = Sendqueue::select()
            ->where('userID', Session::get('uid'))
            ->where('campaign', $id)
            ->where('status', 'pending')
            ->get();

foreach ($records as $record) {
        DB::table('sendqueue')
            ->where('ID', $record->ID)
            ->update(['status' => 'stopped']);
}
```

Comment: I can't get the reason why you're using the query builder while you're actually an instance of your model from your collection. In your foreach statement, simply call $record->update(['status' => 'stopped']). Additionally, if you're having problems with the memory usage, you should consider to avoid the use of the foreach statement and take advantage of the chunk method on your $records collection.

Comment: Another problem will be with the foreach is that if any of record does not update the db then it might cause problem so rather use `Transactions` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $table="user";
public function updateUser($id,$username)
{  
  $resultData = array();
  $updateArray    =   array('user_name'=>$username);
  $update=DB::table('user')
            ->where('user_id', $id)
            ->update($updateArray);


  return $resultData['status'] = true;          
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$my_id = preg_replace ('#[^0-9]#', '', $request->id);
        if (! empty ($my_id)) {
            $this->c->where ('id', $my_id )->update ( [
                    'first_name' => $request->get ( 'first_name' ),
                    'last_name' => $request->get ( 'last_name' ) ,
                    'phone' => $request->get ( 'phone' )
            ] );`enter code here`
            \Session::flash ('message', 'Update Successful');
            return redirect ('customer');
        }
        $this->edit ();
```

http://developer.e-power.com.kh/update-query-in-laravel-5-2/